# Error with react-native run-android after upgrade to react-native version 0.60.4

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am upgrading react-native from 0.59.5 to 0.60.4 with my existing application. But facing a problem as below

```
* Where:
Build file '/home/bingl/Projects/blackstar/frontend/android/app/build.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file '/home/bingl/Projects/blackstar/frontend/android/app/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 57

  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 57
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:184)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:152)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:273)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmDecompiler.parseClass(AsmDecompiler.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findDecompiled(ClassNodeReso
```

And my build.gradle is

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.frontend"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
```

I have absolutely no clue what this error is about and could not find much helpful articles. Please help me out.

Comment: What command do you run to get such error? Building? Bundling?

Comment: Could you change this? `sourceCompatibility  '13'` and `targetCompatibility '13'`

Comment: @KarlTaylor it's `react-native run-android`

Comment: @hongdevelop I changed but the issue still persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Gradle is currently erroring on builds using openJDK-13.

Here's a [Github issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8681) thread.

Check the version of Java and JDK versions on your system by running the following command on in your terminal:

```
file /etc/alternatives/java /etc/alternatives/javac
```

OR

```
file `which java javac`
```

This will list the current installations on your system. If you see `openjdk-13` anywhere, you'll have to downgrade to `openjdk-8`.

Check this [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1133226) for downgrading steps.

Comment: You right, it solves this problem and another coming, looks like I upgrade too early.

Answer (score 16):

For those who are here for `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60`

One of the reason for the same is:

Java version 16 installed which is not yet supported by react-native.

So For MacOS,

```
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
ls
```

- Check the available JDKs
- Remove the jdk-16 if present using this,
  `sudo rm -rf jdk-16.jdk/`

Basically, you can remove JDKs other than `adoptopenjdk-8.jdk` which will be present if you followed [React-Native Env Setup](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup).

Comment: Yes I too face this issue with java 16. Which version is compatible? Do you have any idea?

Comment: @LincyTonita I have mentioned the name of compatible JDK. It is 1.8.0_282 right now, but you can always check react-native env link mentioned for the updated one.

Answer (score 3):

In this file **android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties** change **distributionUrl** on this **distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0-all.zip**

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use this super lightweight utility [jEnv](https://www.jenv.be/) to manage multiple versions of Java on your machine. I've used it for many years with good results.

```sh
$ jenv add /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
openjdk64-1.8.0.292 added
1.8.0.292 added
1.8 added

$ jenv add /usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64/
openjdk64-16.0.1 added
16.0.1 added
16.0 added
16 added
```

Then place a file at `android/.java-version` with the contents:

```
1.8
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer :**.

In `Activity.main`

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Your message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

[image: checkout the output]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).