# while running the react native app with npx react-native run-android Command it gives an error

Tags: android, react-native

Please help me to solve the following error. I didn't understand where is the problem. Node version is v14.18.1, npm version is 6.14.15, java version "16.0.1" ,

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Settings file 'C:\Users\Admin\ReactNativeCode\MyFirstApp\android\settings.gradle'
- What went wrong:
  Could not compile settings file 'C:\Users\Admin\ReactNativeCode\MyFirstApp\android\settings.gradle'.

> startup failed:
> General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 60

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60

this is my bulid.graddle file

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like many had the same error. You can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57338968/error-with-react-native-run-android-after-upgrade-to-react-native-version-0-60-4)

and check the `open-jdk` version installed in your system.

Comment: Thank you I have solved this error but I got another error:  Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Could not start emulator within 30 seconds.. how to solve this error

Comment: You need to manually run the emulator Before `react-native run-android`
open android studio > Tools > AVD Manager > Create Virtual Device

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds#createavd

Comment: As mentioned above I have installed jdk8 and uninstall jdk16 and change the JAVA_HOME variable also but I got the error jdk16 not found how I can solve this error. what should I do